# Facebook type popup drop down lists recreate (image attached)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dhtml

Was hoping someone could point me in the right direction, perhaps to a tutorial on how to create these popup drop down lists like facebooks who liked this link.. I'm assuming its jquery?

[alt text http://2pence.com/pop.jpg](http://2pence.com/pop.jpg)

Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at:

[FaceBox](http://defunkt.github.com/facebox/)

Answer (score 1):

Jquery UI dialog box can give similar results, but you are by no means limited to jquery.
http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

All the box is is a div positioned absolutely in the center of the screen.